# Combine multiple query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count, case

I am firing below queries for getting exam state whether is it fail, pause and pass. Along with other queries are on the page so that my page get lots of time to getting load. I have optimised other query already.

How can I combine those query to get my result fast ? May be all this queries can be combine using "CASE WHEN", Can anyone help me to optimize below query ?

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS countFailMT FROM questionPaper WHERE subjectTopic like 'MT%' result=0)
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS countPauseMT FROM questionPaper WHERE subjectTopic like 'MT%' result=-1)
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS countPassMT FROM questionPaper WHERE subjectTopic like 'MT%' result>=1)

SELECT  COUNT(*) AS countFailEN FROM questionPaper WHERE subjectTopic like 'EN%' result=0)
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS countPauseEN FROM questionPaper WHERE subjectTopic like 'EN%' result=-1)
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS countPassEN FROM questionPaper WHERE subjectTopic like 'EN%' result>=1)
```

Comment: Come on. Try something

Comment: Your `where` conditions are missing an `and`.

Comment: or don't try anything and just kick back and let us do all the work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use conditional aggregation.  This is easy in MySQL:

```
select sum(subjectTopic like 'MT%' and result=0) as countFailMT,
       sum(subjectTopic like 'MT%' and result=-1) as countPauseMT,
       sum(subjectTopic like 'MT%' and result>=1) as countPassMT,
       sum(subjectTopic like 'EN%' and result=0) as countFailEN,
       sum(subjectTopic like 'EN%' and result=-1) as countPauseEN,
       sum(subjectTopic like 'EN%' and result>=1) as countPassEN
from questionPaper;
```

I am assuming the conditions in the `where` clause are connected by `AND` which somehow got lost when the question was created.